# Rails simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am working on a rails 3.0.11 application. for a many to many association I used `simple_fields_for` in a form.

```
simple_form_for @test do |f| 
  f.input :example 
  f.simple_fields_for :services do |builder| 
    render "services_partial", :f => builder
  end 
end
```

Now this is the main form and I used `simple_fields_for` in the form to render the partial of many to many association model called services
In the services partial

```
f.input :example_service 
f.another_service
```

What I want to do is to assign the value of `example_service` attribute to a variable like

```
var = @test.services.example_service
```

but this method is not correct. Can anyone help me that how I can access this for each service. because there may be multiple services.

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand what you're doing. But if you want the values of "example_service" of all services of given @test you can try this

```
some_var = @test.services.collect(&:example_service)
```

some_var is an array of "example_service"-values of all services